# DOM recreation performance problems with nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, performance, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm rendering a calendar UI with AngularJS and I'm running into some pretty big performance issues when flipping through the weeks. Let me explain.

The UI looks something like this:

[image: screenshot of calendar ui]

I loop over all the persons, then for each person I loop over the days, and then render the calendar objects for that user for that day. Something like this (simplified):

```
<div ng-repeat="user in ::ctrl.users track by user.id" class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="day in ctrl.days" class="cell">
        <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items[user.id][day] track by item.id">
            <div class="item">
```

There are not a crazy amount of watcher on this page (about 500), almost everything is bind-once.

The problem is when the user clicks the prev/next buttons to load the previous or next week. This changes the `ctrl.days` array with new days, and all the correct items are loaded. This performs fine until you have a ton of people and calendar items. Then all the destroying and recreating of DOM elements is really slow.

I came across the sly-repeat directive which is meant to cache and reuse DOM elements but because my outer ng-repeat changes (ctrl.days), the inner ng-repeat (with the items) is also recreated. So it doesn't really work.

How can I solve this problem? Right now browsing through the weeks with a large data-set takes about 2 seconds, which is of course not acceptable. With a small set of users and calendar items everything is super snappy.

Comment: generate the DOM for all days (i.e. all weeks) and let the previous and next weeks button change an index. You then use this index to change the visibility (or some other CSS class) of the days. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: A calendar is basically infinite, not really an option to generate all those items up front. Even if I would limit it to 4 weeks, it would still be thousands of DOM elements...

Comment: If your view port size is going to be fixed. You can create the DOM upfront and swap out the values alone. something like 
<div>{{x}}</div><div>{{y}}</div><div>{{z}}</div> where you just change x, y, z instead of looping through a collection of that has x, y and z and creating divs. If I understand correctly your overhead is due to the DOM creation / recreation - so this should help (but at the cost of increased complexity)

Comment: after trying/inventing a lot of solutions to the same problem ... , My conclusion is to use react.js inside a directive . and when  the data updates has to be manual , **controller => directive ** . somthing like `$scope.watch('data' ,function(newval) { myReactDirective.update(newval) });`  this is a bulletproof solutin

Comment: Would react actually solve this? Wouldn't it also recreate all the elements? They are all different between the weeks after all.

Comment: No , React uses shadow dom , which means only recreates the delta between the dom changes , each time the **data** changes.

Comment: That's my point, the delta would be the entire dataset :) It's like I need iOS's UITableView's cell reuse mechanism.

Comment: if you compare shadow dom , to digest cycle . shadow dom is much faster . even if your data only grows. digest cycle's dirty checking + scope creation for each dom elemnt . is real slow comapring to react's rendering . so besides dirty checking , dom creation is faster in react. an easy way to see it is to compare a website written in react vs angular using a mobile phone browser. react.js wins big time ,

Comment: one last thing , plain javascript is much faster than all those $compile $angluar ... helper functions.

Comment: Have u tried this? https://github.com/allaud/quick-ng-repeat

Comment: We ended up using https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat, quite happy with that.

Comment: you can also probably get rid of one of the ng-repeats as the number of days on the page is probably not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `track by` in your nested ng-repeats. This will prevent them from reloading unnecessary inner repeats. For more information, see:

http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

Comment: That doesn't help since all the items are unique. And when the outer repeat changes, the inner repeat would change anyway.

Comment: We ended up using https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat, it works very well for us.